# Conditional Filling in Missing Values in a Pandas Data frame using non-conventional means

Tags: python, pandas

TLDR; ***How can I improve my code and make it more pythonic?***

Hi,

One of the interesting challenge(s) we were given in a tutorial was the following:
"There are X missing entries in the data frame with an associated code but a 'blank' entry next to the code. This is a random occurance across the data frame. Using your knowledge of pandas, map each missing 'blank' entry to the associated code."

So this looks like the following:

```
|code| |name|
001     Australia
002     London
...
001    <blank>
```

My approach I have used is as follows:

Loop through entire dataframe and identify areas with blanks "". Replace all blanks via copying the associated correct code (ordered) to the dataframe.

```
code_names = [ "",
    'Economic management', 
    'Public sector governance', 
    'Rule of law',
    'Financial and private sector development', 
    'Trade and integration', 
    'Social protection and risk management', 
    'Social dev/gender/inclusion', 
    'Human development', 
    'Urban development', 
    'Rural development', 
    'Environment and natural resources management'
]

df_copy = df_.copy()

# Looks through each code name, and if it is empty, stores the proper name in its place
for x in range(len(df_copy.mjtheme_namecode)):
    for y in range(len(df_copy.mjtheme_namecode[x])):
        if(df_copy.mjtheme_namecode[x][y]['name'] == ""):
            df_copy.mjtheme_namecode[x][y]['name'] = code_names[int(df_copy.mjtheme_namecode[x][y]['code'])]

limit = 25
counter = 0

for x in range(len(df_copy.mjtheme_namecode)):
    for y in range(len(df_copy.mjtheme_namecode[x])):
        print(df_copy.mjtheme_namecode[x][y])
        counter += 1
    if(counter >= limit):
        break
```

While the above approach works - is there a better, more pythonic way of achieving what I'm after? I feel the approach I have used is very clunky due to my skills not being very well developed.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1:**

One way to do this would be to replace all your `""` blanks with `NaN`, sort the dataframe by `code` and `name`, and use [`fillna(method='ffill')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

Starting with this:

```
>>> df
   code       name
0     1  Australia
1     2     London
2     1
```

You can apply the following:

```
new_df = (df.replace({'name':{'':np.nan}})
          .sort_values(['code', 'name'])
          .fillna(method='ffill')
          .sort_index())

>>> new_df
   code       name
0     1  Australia
1     2     London
2     1  Australia
```

**Method 2:**

This is more convoluted, but will work as well:
Using `groupby`, `first`, and `sqeeze`, you can create a `pd.Series` to map the codes to non-blank names, and use `.map` to map that series to your `code` column:

```
df['name'] = (df['code']
              .map(
                  df.replace({'name':{'':np.nan}})
                  .sort_values(['code', 'name'])
                  .groupby('code')
                  .first()
                  .squeeze()
              ))

>>> df
   code       name
0     1  Australia
1     2     London
2     1  Australia
```

**Explanation:** The `pd.Series` map that this creates looks like this:

```
code
1    Australia
2       London
```

And it works because it gets the first instance for every code (via the `groupby`), sorted in such a manner that the `NaN`s are last. So as long as each code is associated with a name, this method will work.

Comment: Oh wow, I had no idea you could use map in that respect.Could you please explain how the sort values, groupby and first does in this context?

How I see it is that you have replaced all missing values with a NaN;
You have then sorted the values (code and name) - so all the NaNs will be sorted alongside each other.

You then groupby the 'code' column - what for though?